# Convert Angular application to library

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have a Angular application and I would like to export it as a library.

What I am trying to aim is to convert it as a library (and publish it) to be able to use that whole application into another app I have, as a node_modules.

You can find [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTVGQ.png) the architecture of the application.

Note that the app component contains a AppModule, a AppComponent and different homemade components.

I have some lead with the "yarn build" command but I doesn't understand how to then export the library (since what's keeping everything together in my application is the AppModule).

How can I achieve my goal ?

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Either you have an application, which is able to run in the browser. Or you have a library, which contains re-usable components / services /..., and is published via an NPM package and can be used in another application. Why are you trying to publish an application as a library?

Comment: Also, did you read the documentation? https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

Comment: The application is basically a canvas that I designed (as an application) but now I want to "convert" it as a library to be able to reuse that canvas in an another application.
Exporting it as a library is something I want to do since it will also help me reuse it in future apps.

About the library documentation, I did checked it but it is unclear to me since it's about creating a library from the beginning where I started as an application

Comment: In this case, open the link I sent and follow the steps to create a library. Then copy your code inside that library.

Comment: With the AppModule and everything, that's where I block honestly.

Should I rename the AppModule in something else ?
Doing so, where do I put my components in the app folder ?

Or maybe there is something I didn't understand in your answer

Comment: Your question is too broad to give you a good answer. I'd recommend you to do some more research and look at some examples, for example this one: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packaged